# Why does git merge sometimes remove changes when it shouldn't?

Tags: git, git-merge

Every so often, I've been experiencing some strange behavior in git. where changes I make to a file in one branch are removed when I merge in another branch in which unrelated changes have been made to the same file.

Let's say I start in branch master. Here's the rough outline of what happens:

```
vim foo.txt
git add foo.txt
git commit

git checkout -b test
vim foo.txt
git commit -a -m added a new line to foo.txt

git checkout master
vim foo.txt
git commit -a -m made some unrelated change

git merge test
```

At this point, I will discover that the change I made in foo.txt in the master branch has been removed.

I am making many other changes and performing other git operations in the middle of all of this. Since merges like this are the entire point of git, I feel like I am probably doing something wrong, at some point.

Does anyone have any idea what?

Comment: Can you be more specific, what exactly where the changes? Were there any conflicts? What did the merge file look like?

Comment: I think you'll need to be a little bit clearer on what the other operations you're performing "in the middle of all of this". I've been using Git for several years and haven't seen it remove changes without me instructing it to do so.

Comment: Mainly other commits and merges, in both branches. This kind of thing happens even when no conflicts are mentioned.

Comment: I've checked your steps and the don't lead to any problems (nor seems they should)

Answer (score 1):

because the commit on the test branch was made last and test has a commit that can resolve a common ancestor commit, then the default behaviour is to use the new information from test as the most up-to-date information. you can force the behaviour by using the -s option. See this link for examples: http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html

EDITED with workflow example

```
mkdir showoff_git
cd showoff_git
git init
touch file_a
echo "line 1" >> file_a
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"
git checkout -b test
sed -i='' s/1/2/ file_a
git add .
git commit -m "bluffing"
git checkout master
git merge -s ours test
```

Comment: This sounds promising but I'm not quite sure what you mean. Why does anything need to be resolved? Shouldn't both changes be taken into account?

Also, which -s-specified strategy would fix this problem?

Comment: `git merge -s ours test` would be what you want i think.

Comment: I tried this out, but I'm not entirely convinced -- couldn't this cause problems by silently ignoring changes in the branch I'm merging in?

I apologize if I'm being slow, but I would really appreciate it if you could explain your point about the "common ancestor commit." I've been googling and trying to reproduce the problem for the past few hours but I think I am still missing what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Thanks to that, I've found out the problem is something else. About to submit a new question...